# Adding bootstrap to angular 12.1.4 - unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to install bootstrap in a new angular app but it doesn't work

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

I get this error below, what do I need to do to fix this?

```
The package @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@10.0.0 will be installed and executed.  
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: how-to-test@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@12.1.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~12.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"12.2.0" from @angular/localize@12.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   peer @angular/localize@"^12.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@10.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"10.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a 
full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-04T19_50_44_840Z-debug.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
```

my angular version details are as follows

```
Angular CLI: 12.1.4
Node: 15.8.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 7.20.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.1.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1201.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.1.4
@angular-devkit/core            12.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.1.4
@angular/cli                    12.1.4
@schematics/angular             12.1.4
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
```

Can anyone help with a good answer? as all of this seems to work one day they doesn't the next.

**Update 05/08/2021**

I still cant get it working, I tried these steps.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@12.0.0
```

I uninstalled and re-installed node.js as well, version 14.17.4

```
npm uninstall --save-dev @angular/cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@12.0.0

npm install
```

running

```
ng version
```

give me this:

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.0
Node: 14.17.4
Package Manager: npm 7.20.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.0.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1200.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.0.5
@angular-devkit/core            12.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.0
@angular/cli                    12.2.0
@schematics/angular             12.2.0
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.2.4
```

Then again when I run this

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

I get a similar issue with the @angular/compiler.
This is located in the **package-lock.json** file. Why does it say 12.0.5 when I installed 12.0.0. (ruddy confusing)?

```
The package @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@10.0.0 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: how-to-test@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@12.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~12.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"12.2.0" from @angular/localize@12.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   peer @angular/localize@"^12.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@10.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"10.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

Comment: The ngBootstrap team [just recently added Angular 12.0 support](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). You may be on a minor/patch version that isn't yet supported. Maybe pull back to 12.0.x and see what happens.

Comment: how about ... ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --force

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First way:** Install `bootstrap` in your `angular 12` app like below. This is only for `css` importing.

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Now you need to import `bootstrap css` in `style.css` file like this:

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

**Second way:** Install `bootstrap` with `jquery` and `popper js` like below and thus you can import `bootstrap css` and `bootstrap js` function.

```
npm install bootstrap --save
npm install jquery --save
npm install popper.js --save
```

After successfully run the above commands import it in `angular.json` file like this:

```
 "styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "src/styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ]
```

Now you can easily use bootstrap class, css, js as expected :)

Comment: Yea I gave up with the ng-bootstrap and just did he first two steps, many thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can paste the **Bootstrap CSS** link directly into your Angular **index.html** file in the head section.

[image]

Here's the link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: but this does not solve the problem when running the "ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" command

Answer (score -2):

You can install bootstrap through NPM command. try the below code

`npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

This will surely works!

Reference:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Comment: No same issue running that as well